# Flutter localization: Formatting issue in app_en.arb

Tags: flutter, localization, flutter-localizations

This is my `app_en.arb` file:

```
{
    "app_title": "Results and standings",
    "results": "Results",
    "standings": "Standings",
}
```

However, when I run `flutter gen-l10n`, the console prompted the following error which I don't understand why, because it appears nothing wrong with the closing curly brace.

```
/race_standings/lib/localization/l10n/app_en.arb has the following formatting issue:

FormatException: Unexpected character (at line 5, character 1)
}
```

Can anyone help? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I found that there should be **no trailing comma after the last entry**, like this:

```
{
  "app_title": "Results and standings",
  "results": "Results",
  "standings": "Standings"
}
```